# How do I add textboxes dynamically in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, dom, textbox

By default I have 5 textboxes. When a user clicks on a button, one textbox should be added.

How could I do this?

Answer (score 24):

If you replace the innerHTML, the previously entered values will be cleared, to avoid that, you can append the input elements programmatically:

```
var input = document.createElement('input'); 
input.type = "text"; 
//...    
container.appendChild(input);
```

Check [this](http://jsbin.com/amute/edit) example.

Comment: Correct answer - because innerHTML will replace the contents of the specified HTML element with the newly defined innerHTML value.

Answer (score 12):

Javascript Function

```
function add() {

//Create an input type dynamically.
var element = document.createElement("input");

//Create Labels
var label = document.createElement("Label");
label.innerHTML = "New Label";     

//Assign different attributes to the element.
element.setAttribute("type", "text");
element.setAttribute("value", "");
element.setAttribute("name", "Test Name");
element.setAttribute("style", "width:200px");

label.setAttribute("style", "font-weight:normal");

// 'foobar' is the div id, where new fields are to be added
var foo = document.getElementById("fooBar");

//Append the element in page (in span).
foo.appendChild(label);
foo.appendChild(element);
}
```

Html part,

```
<button id="button" value="Add" onClick:"javascript:add();">
```

And, Its done!

Comment: Here, you can set attributes for textbox. such as css properties, values, id, etc

Answer (score 2):

```
<script>
function add()
{
    document.getElementById("place").innerHTML="<input type='text' value=''>"
}
</script>
<input type="button" value="clickMe" onClick="add();">
<div id="place"></div>
```

Comment: Whomever voted for this, isn't aware of the impact of using innerHTML.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
function add()
{
    var inpt = document.getElementById('input_template');
    inpt.parentNode.appendChild(inpt.cloneNode(false));
}
</script>

<input type="button" onclick="add();">
```

set id=input_template to one of the predefined textboxes

Comment: I would have made it a separate function instead of inline, and I would have used CSS to keep the styles the same, but this does seem like a clever way to do it, and it does seem it would work.

Answer (score 0):

Best would be to attach an event on to the `onclick` of the button, that will set a div's visibility to `inline`. This is about the best way I can see for this, considering flexibility and robustness.

Have a [look here](http://lists.evolt.org/archive/Week-of-Mon-20020624/116151.html) for example code.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Dynamic Form</title>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" >
function changeIt()
{

createTextbox.innerHTML = createTextbox.innerHTML +"<br><input type='text' name='mytext' >"

}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form name="form">
<input type="button" value="clickHere" onClick="changeIt()">
<div id="createTextbox"></div>
</form> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Whomever voted for this, isn't aware of the impact of using innerHTML.

Comment: -1. Mucking about with `innerHTML` when a simple `appendChild()` would work is unnecessarily slow, and what is going on with your `i` variable?  It doesn't even get used because the variable isn't expanded in the `innerHTML` string, so your HTML becomes `name='mytext'` followed by garbage that the browser can't understand.

Comment: Writing to innerHTML once is fair enough; += on innerHTML is always a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

by change for loop values we can generate textboxes dynamically

```js
function addFunction() {
  var table = document.getElementById("textbox");
  var rowlen = table.rows.length;
  var row = table.insertRow(rowlen);
  row.id = rowlen;
  var arr = ['textboxfiledname'];
  for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    var x = row.insertCell(i)
    if (i == 1) {
      x.innerHTML = "<input type='button' onclick='removeCell(" + row.id + ")' value=Delete>"
    } else {
      x.innerHTML = "<label>" + arr[i] + ":</label><input type='textbox' name='" + arr[i] + "'>"
    }
  }
}

function removeCell(rowid) {
  var table = document.getElementById(rowid).remove();
}
```

```css
input[type=text] {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
  padding: 15px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  resize: vertical;
}

label {
  padding: 12px 12px 12px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

input[type=button] {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 6px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<fieldset style="margin-left:20%;margin-right:20%;font-family:sans-serif;padding:15px;border-radius:5px;background:#f2f2f2;border:5px solid #1F497D">
  <legend style="background:#1F497D;color:#fff;padding:5px 10px;font-size:22px;border-radius:5px;margin-left:20px;box-shadow:0 0 0 5px #ddd">DynamicTextbox</legend>
  <table id="textbox">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="button" onclick="addFunction()" value="AddTextbox" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
The best I can help is with this code
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
    <body>
      <input type=text id="chat" placeholder="Enter a message..." maxlength="120">
      <input type=Button id="Button" value="Test" onClick="T()">
      <h1 id="message"></h1>

    <script>
    function T() {
      var m = document.getElementById("chat").value
      document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = m
    }
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).