# How to add more textbox by other textbox value

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, dynamic, textbox, runtime

I have a problem is how to add more textbox by enter a value in other textbox. Anybody if have any ideas please help me. Thank you in advance

Comment: post some code and you want in server side or client side?

Comment: How are you doing now?

Comment: @skhurams i don't know how to code. i wanna in client-side

Comment: @PiLHA i think use textbox_changed event, but i don't know how

Answer (score 0):

you could manipulate the dom-model and add the textboxes dynamically..but the first question is: do you need the textboxes on the server side on the postback?

Comment: in client-side. When user enter a new value in textbox. A list of textboxes like date, name, age will be added. Thank you

Comment: here is an link about how a textbox get added dynamically to the dom [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1390319/how-do-i-add-textboxes-dynamically-in-javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1390319/how-do-i-add-textboxes-dynamically-in-javascript). but these textboxes don't get rendered by the server (runat=server) so you have to access them by the Request.Form object if you need the values