# Add Textbox by a click of a button using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

Is it possible to add text boxes into an iframe of the same domain. So i have created a button for the user to click.

```
<button id="text" onclick="addTextBox()">Text</button>
```

As the user clicks on the button, I need a text box added within the iframe.

```
<iframe id="iframeDiv" class="section"></iframe>
```

I have tried this

**JS:**

```
function addTextBox() {

    var text = '<div><textarea name="textbox" id="textbox" cols="10" rows="1"></textarea></div>';

    var iframe = document.getElementById('iframeDiv'),
        iframe.innerHTML += parent.text;

    $('div').draggable({
        cancel: "textbox",
        start: function () {
            $('#textbox').focus();
        },
        stop: function () {
            $('#textbox').focus();
        }
    });

}

window.onload = function () {
    addTextBox();

    return;
}
```

I have done a fiddle too: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/J_patel/nd24B/)

I also want to understand how the text tag can be appended to the DOM structure

Comment: Use `document.createElement(nodename)`

Comment: why you add textbox in iframe instead of a div

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1390319/how-do-i-add-textboxes-dynamically-in-javascript

Comment: Your fiddle is broken...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use document.createElement for creating element or use jQuery to create element in a easier way.
And use iframe.contentWindow.document.body.appendChild to have multiple elements

```
     function addTextBox() {    
        var text = document.createElement('textarea'),
        iframe = document.getElementById('iframeDiv');
        text.setAttribute('id', 'textbox');

        iframe.contentWindow.document.body.appendChild(text);    
     }
```

Or you can also do this:

```
    function addTextBox() {    
        var text = '<div><textarea name="textbox" id="textbox" cols="10" rows="1"> </textarea></div>',
        iframe = document.getElementById('iframeDiv');
        iframe.contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML = text;    
    }
```

Comment: Thank you. I prefer the first suggestion as I can add multiple textboxes. Though I'm trying to make the textbox draggable too. Where can I add the draggable function. or something similar to this

   $('textarea').draggable({
        cancel: "textbox",
        start: function () {
            $('#textbox').focus();
        },
        stop: function () {
            $('#textbox').focus();
        }
    });

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 var text = '<div><textarea name="textbox" id="textbox" cols="10" rows="1"></textarea></div>';
    var iframe = document.getElementById('iframeDiv');
iframe .src = "data:text/html;charset=utf-8," + escape(text);
```

see [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/nd24B/3/)