# display a textbox if user select "Other" on the drop down menu retrieved from the database

Tags: javascript, php

pls help me with this one. I can't display the textbox if the user selects "Other" option in the drop down menu. the values in the drop down came from the database. thanks! :)

```
 <th align="left" height="26" colspan="3"><strong>Return Reason Codes:</strong><span class="select">
      <?php

            echo "<select description='returnreason' type='text' id='returnreason' onchange=' showfield(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)'>";
            echo '<option id="0">'.'    --Select Return Reason--  '.'</option>';
            $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM preturnreason");
            while($record = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) 
                   {
                    echo '<option value=" '.$record['DESCRIPTION'].'">'.$record['DESCRIPTION']. '</option>';

                   }        
            echo '</select>';

         ?> <div id="div1"></div></th>
    </tr>
```

and here's my javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function showfield(name){
  if(name=='Other')document.getElementById('div1').innerHTML='Other: <input type="text" name="other" />';
  else document.getElementById('div1').innerHTML='';
}
</script>
```

Comment: 1) `<option id="0">` id should not be zero
2)check what `name` returns

Answer (score 0):

```
    var input = document.createElement('input'); 
input.type = "text"; 
div1.appendChild(input);
```

stackoverflow. LINK
[How do I add textboxes dynamically in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1390319/how-do-i-add-textboxes-dynamically-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Your Code :

```
 <?php    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM preturnreason");?>
<th align="left" height="26" colspan="3"><strong>Return Reason Codes:</strong><span class="select">
<select description='returnreason' id='returnreason' >
    <option value="999">--Select Return Reason--</option>';
   <?php
        while($record = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) 
               { ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $record['DESCRIPTION'] ?>"> <?php echo $record['DESCRIPTION'] ?> </option>

            <?php  } ?>
    <option value="0">Other</option>';
</select>

     ?> <div id="myTxt"></div></th>
</tr>
```

Below is my sample code which gives demo to display a text-box if user select “Other” on the drop down menu.

HTML

```
<select id='sBox' onselect='chkOption()'>
<option value='9'>Select</option>
<option value='0'>Other</option>
<option value='1'>One</option>
</select>

<div id='myTxt' style="display: none">
    <input type='text'>
</div>
```

JQuery

```
$('select').on('change', function() {

if( this.value  == '0')
  $("#myTxt").show();
else
    $("#myTxt").hide();
})
```

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ghLc9/)**

Comment: it's working but I got the values from the database. I didn't use the <option> tags to display the values. But this one is great! :) @A.P.

Comment: it just display another drop down box aside from what I created b4

Answer (score 0):

(Answer based on A.P.'s answer)
If you'd rather use pure JS (no Jquery) you can use the following code:

```
<select id='sBox' onChange='checkchange()'>
    <option value='9'>Select</option>
    <option value='0'>Other</option>
    <option value='1'>One</option>
</select>

<div id='myTxt' style="display: none">
    <input type='text'>
</div>
```

and Javascript:

```
function checkchange() {
  if(document.getElementById('sBox').value == '0') {
    document.getElementById('myTxt').style.display='block';
  }
  else {
    document.getElementById('myTxt').style.display='none';
  }
};
```

Jsfiddle: [here](http://jsfiddle.net/RN8dN/)

Combining that to your code:

```
<th align="left" height="26" colspan="3"><strong>Return Reason Codes:</strong><span class="select">
<select description='returnreason' id='returnreason' onchange=' checkchange()'>
  <option id="0">   --Select Return Reason--  </option>
  <?php
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM preturnreason");
    while($record = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
      echo '<option value=" '.$record['DESCRIPTION'].'">'.$record['DESCRIPTION']. '</option>';
    }
  ?>
  <option value='other'>Other - please specify</option>
</select>
<div id="div1"><input type='text'></div></th>
</tr>

<script>
function checkchange() {
  if(document.getElementById('returnreason').value == 'other') {
    document.getElementById('div1').style.display='block';
  }
  else {
    document.getElementById('div1').style.display='none';
  }
}
</script>
```